# PyQt4: How to reorder child widgets?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4

I want to implement a GUI program like the blueprint editor in the Unreal game engine with PyQt4. Here is an example of the blueprint editor:

[image]

First I create a simple container widget to place all the components(The rectangles). Then I use the `QPainterPath` widget to draw lines to connect the components. Since the users can place the components wherever they want by drag and drop, I choose absolute positioning in my container widget. Here is the sample code:

```
class Component(QtGui.QWidget):
    """A simple rectangle."""
    def __init__(self, type_, parent=None):
        super(Component, self).__init__(parent)
        ...

class BezierPath(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, start, end, parent=None):
        super(BezierPath, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setMinimumSize(300, 500)
        self._start = start
        self._end = end
        self._path = self._generate_path(self._start, self._end)
        self.setMinimumSize(
            abs(start.x()-end.x()), abs(start.y()-end.y()))

    def _generate_path(self, start, end):
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.moveTo(start)
        central_x = (start.x()+end.x())*0.5
        path.cubicTo(
            QtCore.QPointF(central_x, start.y()),
            QtCore.QPointF(central_x, end.y()),
            end)
        return path

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(self)
        pen = QtGui.QPen()
        pen.setWidth(3)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.drawPath(self._path)
        painter.end()

class Container(QtGui.QWidget):
    def add_component(self, component_type, position):
        component = Component(component_type, self)
        component.move(position)

    def add_connection(self, component_a, component_b):
        bezier_path = BezierPath(component_a.pos(), component_b.pose(), self)
```

The problem is I want to lines show underneath the components, but the components are created first. Is there a way I can reorder the child widgets of the `Container` of should I use a better way to organize the components?

Comment: I did something similiar recently: I choosed QGraphicsView Framework to realize it. Maybe worth to think about switching. The QGraphicsView allows easy controll over the presentation of the graph. Other words for those UI (which I found quite usefull while researching): Flow Based UI, Node based UI. Sorry that this is no Answer but I currently dont have the time to work through your code. Good Luck!

Comment: I would also recommend using the QGraphicsView framework, definitely. It's made for flexible 2D-interfaces. You have an example of a node link diagram editor here: https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/blob/master/examples/graphicsview/diagramscene/diagramscene.py. If you want to embed more complex widgets you can do that with QGraphicsProxyWidgetItem (http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qgraphicsproxywidget.html).

Comment: @Mailerdaimon @RickardSjogren Thanks you. I'will look at QGraphicsView. At the same time, I found a temporary solution: add a widget in the `Container`, make sure it's on the bottom, then add all the `BezierPath` in that widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for reordering the child widgets myself. I'll mark this answer as accepted for now. It's not a perfect solution so if there is a better answer I will accept it then. Anyway here is the solution:

In qt4 the widget has a method [`raise_()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#raise), here I quote:

> to raises this widget to the top of the parent widget's stack. After
>   this call the widget will be visually in front of any overlapping
>   sibling widgets.

So if you want to reorder all your widgets, first you keep the references of all the child widgets in you own list or what container you choose. Reorder all the widgets in you own container, then call `raise_()` for each widget in reverse order.